# Python: A better way to write n compositions of a function?

Tags: python, function, composition

I wrote a function "rep" that takes a function f and takes n compositions of f.
So rep(square,3) behaves like this: square(square(square(x))).
And when I pass 3 into it, rep(square,3)(3)=6561.

There is no problem with my code, but I was wondering if there was a way to make it "prettier" (or shorter) without having to call another function or import anything. Thanks!

```
def compose1(f, g):
    """Return a function h, such that h(x) = f(g(x))."""
    def h(x):
        return f(g(x))
    return h

def rep(f,n):
    newfunc = f
    count=1
    while count < n:
        newfunc = compose1(f,newfunc)
        count+=1
    return newfunc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for speed, the `for` loop is clearly the way to go.  But if you're looking for theoretical academic acceptance ;-), stick to terse functional idioms.  Like:

```
def rep(f, n):
    return f if n == 1 else lambda x: f(rep(f, n-1)(x))
```

Comment: Well, step through it. Suppose `n` is 2. Then `rep(f, 2)` returns `lambda x: f(rep(f, 1)(x))`. If you call that on, say, `8.4`, that becomes `f(rep(f, 1)(8.4))`. The `rep(f, 1)` part returns `f`, so that's `f(f(8.4))`. Now try an `n` of 3 on your own ;-) Generally speaking, anywhere you see iteration you *could* use recursion instead, and vice versa. In functional languages recursion is often more natural; in Python, iteration is often more natural.

Comment: ahhh I like this. I hadn't learned recursion until this morning. I didn't look into your solution because I didn't want to spoil anything for myself. I answered my original question with recursion and it looked nearly identical to yours! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
def rep(f, n):
    def repeated(x):
        for i in xrange(n):
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return repeated
```

Using a `for` loop instead of `while` is shorter and more readable, and `compose1` doesn't really need to be a separate function.

Comment: This approach has another advantage: it will handle `rep(lambda x: x**2, 10**4)(1.0)`, whereas the original won't due to Python's recursion limits.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe someone will find this solution useful

Compose number of functions

```
from functools import reduce

def compose(*functions):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: (lambda arg: x(y(arg))), functions)
```

Use list comprehensions to generate list of functions

```
def multi(how_many, func):
    return compose(*[func for num in range(how_many)])
```

Usage

```
def square(x):
    return x * x

multi(3, square)(3) == 6561
```

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that repeated composition of the same function is best done with a loop, you could use `*args` to compose an arbitrary number of functions:

```
def identity(x):
    return x

def compose(*funcs):
    if funcs:
        rest = compose(*funcs[1:])
        return lambda x: funcs[0](rest(x))
    else:
        return identity
```

And in this case you would have:

```
def rep(f,n):
    funcs = (f,)*n # tuple with f repeated n times
    return compose(*funcs)
```

And as DSM kindly pointed out in the comments, you could remove the recursion like so:

```
def compose(*funcs):
    if not funcs:
        return identity
    else:
        def composed(x):
            for f in reversed(funcs):
                x = f(x)
            return x
        return composed
```

(also note that you can replace `x` with `*args` if you also want to support arbitrary arguments to the functions you're composing, but I left it at one argument since that's how you have it in the original problem)

Comment: You could combine the ideas: you can loop over `funcs` in reverse in `compose` in the returned `h`.