# Is there any way to make Python's functions of functions more readable?

Tags: python, function

I have written the following code in Python involving multiple functions in one single argument "x":

```
stemming(removeStopWords(stringToList(removeRepChar(charOk(x)))))
```

I want to know if I can do something to make that code more readable (if it isn't already readable enough). Can I omit those parentheses somehow as in other programming languages? For example in Haskell:

```
stemming $ removeStopWords $ stringToList $ removeRepChar $ charOk x
```

or a point-free approach

```
funct = stemming.removeStopWords.stringToList.removeRepChar.charOk

funct(x)
```

I'm concerned about the case in which I have hundreds of parentheses and functions like those that possibly can turn into a boring bigger code:

```
function1(function2(function3( ... (function300(x)) ... )))
```

I know Python is not a pure functional language but one never knows

Comment: You can add linebreaks, or intermediate variables, ...

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852263/python-a-better-way-to-write-n-compositions-of-a-function

Comment: Oh, thanks. Now tell me: in your opinion do you think that way I've shown is readable or I  still need to add linebreaks and intermediate variables?

Comment: For example, I've just done this line: transformed_cells = map(lambda x: ''.join(stemming(splitWord(removeStopWords(stringToList(removeRepChar(charOk(x))))))), df)

Comment: The example you have shown would be more readable in my opinion if it were split to more than one line.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this on Code Review. It seems you are dealing with Pandas for which there might be a better solution altogether.

Comment: Yeah I'm using Pandas and I'm just trying to process my data but I don't know much of it. By the way, can you tell me more about this Code Review stuff ?

Comment: You can do method chaining `charOk(x).removeRepChar().stringToList().removeStopWords().stemming()` as long as each of those calls returns an object with the next method on it. That's now it works for pandas for instance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get it. @tdelaney I'm not sure what I did wrong but my problem is to apply these functions to a dataframe of one column.

Comment: @testing_22 - and these are functions that you wrote? You could put these functions in a class and do method chaining.

Comment: Yes I wrote them and they are not in any class (yet)

Comment: Simply spread it across lines using intermediate variables to improve readability: one-liners are a contra-indication for readability.

Comment: Yeah! I should do that anyways, thank you barny and mkrieger1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options you could try. One is to write your own 'apply' that takes functions and an argument.

```
def apply_functions(functions, arg):
    for fctn in functions:
        arg = fctn(arg)
    return arg

result = apply_functions((charOk, removeRepChar, stringToList,
    removeStopWords), x)
```

Another is to put your functions into a class and use method chaining. You already have functions that return the value, just return `self` instead.

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def charOk(self):
        # do the operation
        return self

    def removeRepChar(self):
        # do the operation
        return self

    etc...

result = Foo(x).charOk().removeRepChar().stringToList().removeStopWords()
```

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thank you so much! Personally I'd rather use the first approach (since I'd probably have to rewrite those functions if they were in class)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd just use the "native" Python way with brackets, but here's a slightly different spin on the [answer by tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63430568/1639625), with a `Chain` class using [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to provide *any* function defined in the [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) scope.

```
class Chain:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __getattr__(self, f):
        return lambda: Chain(globals()[f](self.val))

def upper(s):
    return s.upper()

def pad(s):
    return "abc" + s + "xyz"
    
def swap(s):
    return s.swapcase()

print(Chain("foo").upper().pad().swap().val)
# ABCfooXYZ
```

Or use `partial` and `reduce` to create a `compose` function (although I have the feeling like something like this should already exist):

```
from functools import reduce, partial

def compose(*fs):
    return partial(reduce, lambda x, f: f(x), fs)

print(compose(upper, pad, swap)("foo"))
```

Comment: Wow! Incredible!! So I just need to define those two methods on class and I'm done? Btw, do you mind explaining me better __getattr__ method?